# Storing string inside a C struct

Tags: c, string, memory-management, struct

As a Computer Science homework, I was asked to make an algorithm that uses this code underneath. The problem is, the string inside the Name struct is beign stored as a pointer, so when I get the next input, all strings are the same and that breaks the functionality of my complete code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_CAP 5
#define SUCCESS 1
#define FAILURE 0
#define MAX_LINES 100000

typedef struct Name
{
  char *string;
} Name;

Name *initializeName(char *inputedName)
{
  Name *name = calloc(1, sizeof(Name));
  if (name != NULL)
  {
    name->string = inputedName;
  }
  return name;
}

void printName(Name *name){
  printf("Name -> %s\n", name->string);
}

int main() {

    Name **name;

    for(int i=0; i< 3; i++) {
        char string[100];
        scanf("%s", string);
        name[i] = initializeName(string);
        for(int j = 0; j<=i;j++) {
            printName(name[i]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This is a test code with the broken functionality mentioned. It scanfs a string and stores it inside a name and puts the name inside an Name array.

How do I make Name->string be stored as a string?

Comment: Don't just copy the pointer (`name->string = inputedName`); allocate new storage and copy the string contents.

Comment: @n.m. I couldnt solve the issue with the referenced question. Altough they might be superficially related, I believe they treat different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've allocated the `struct Name`, you can then go ahead and allocate space to store a copy of the string itself:

```
if (name != NULL)
{
    /* +1 for null terminator at end of string */
    size_t string_length = strlen(inputedName) + 1;

    name->string = calloc(string_length, 1);
```

If that succeeds, you can then copy the string into the newly allocated space (if it fails, you need to free the `struct Name` allocated):

```
    if (name->string != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(name->string, inputedName, string_length);
    }
    else
    {
        free(name);
        name = NULL;
    }
```

---

You also have an error in `main()`.  `Name **name;` is a pointer, but it doesn't point anywhere yet, so you can't access `name[i]`.  Your `for()` loop only accesses from `name[0]` to `name[2]`, so changing the definition to an array of three `Name *` pointers will fix it:

```
Name *name[3];
```

Comment: Even after making these changes, the strings inside the Name array are all the same.
Here is how it happens:
`string1` outputs `Name -> string1` | `string 2` outputs `Name -> string2\nName -> string2`

Comment: @victormoraesgs: After this change the strings inside each `Name` are different, but your loop always prints the same strings, because it loops over `j` but prints `name[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
name->string = inputedName;
```

doesn't copy the string. You want `strdup`

```
name->string = strdup(imputedName);
```

Comment: @bigdataolddriver: It isn't. He has a `calloc` two lines above already.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver is correct - the error he's referring to is in `main`, where `Name **name;` is declared and `name[i]` is then accessed with no memory allocation.

Comment: oh yes I had a strange feeling after  accepting  @joshua  the explanation of ```calloc``` called . and I looked up and down again and again till @caf  pointed out

Comment: Even after initializing the array and using strdup, the strings still are the same

Comment: @victormoraesgs: As caf already pointed out you have a typo here `printName(name[i]);` shold read `printName(name[j]);`.

Comment: @Joshua you are absolutely right, thank you very much! It is now working properly and I have accepted this as the correct answer.

Comment: @victormoraesgs: Note that `strdup()` is a POSIX function, but not standard C.  That may or may not matter for your course.